# Pandas DataFrame merge choosing the higher value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames like this:

```
         1          2          3 
0   61.579   0.000000  47.279861
1    0.000   0.000000   0.000000
2   62.700   9.180000  48.479861
3   56.100  40.180000  71.679861
4   73.100  50.930000  71.679861
5   88.300  37.930000  36.479861
```

I need to merge them choosing each time the higher value. All the values are float.
Any ideas? I have to loop on the DataFrames?

Comment: The @jezrael solution is working well. The second DataFrame si build in the same way.

Answer (score 12):

You need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) first and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` and aggregate `max`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0:[4,5,4],
                    1:[7,8,9]})

print (df1)
   0  1
0  4  7
1  5  8
2  4  9


df2 = pd.DataFrame({0:[8,5,6],
                    1:[9,4,4]})

print (df2)
   0  1
0  8  9
1  5  4
2  6  4

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).max()
print (df)
   0  1
0  8  9
1  5  8
2  6  9
```

If need faster solution use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = df1.values
b = df2.values
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(a > b, a, b), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df)
   0  1
0  8  9
1  5  8
2  6  9
```

Comment: @Max - Glad can help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.where(df1>df2, df2)
```

is doing same job, but not faster than 
`np.where`